# Calling JS functions with button elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having difficulty calling a JavaScript function to play a video using a button element. My function script is as follows:

```
    <button onclick = "PlayVid()">Play</button>
        <button onclick = "PauseVid()">Pause</button>
        <button onclick = "MaxScreen()">Full Screen</button>
        <button onclick = "NorScreen()">Normal Size</button>
        <div class = "video">
        <video>
            <source src="YellowEyePenguinVid.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
            </video>
        </div>




    <script>
    var Video = document.getElementById("YellowEyePenguinVid"); 
        function PlayVid()
       {
            vid.play(); 
       }
        function PauseVid()
        {
            vid.pause();
        }
        function MaxScreen() 
        {
            Video.width = 560;
        }
        function NorScreen()
        {   
            Video.width = 260;  <!-- Brings video back to original size -->
        }
        </script>
```

I have declared the function that each button should call from but they are unresponsive. I've also tried quoting the name of the video inside the brackets but that doesn't work either. Could someone point out where i'm going wrong? This is the layout for other JS I have on my site and function is called successfully.

Thanks

Comment: You've used `vid.play();` and `vid.pause();`. Shouldn't it be `Video` instead of `vid` ?

Comment: Also, your `<video>` element doesn't have any ID.

Comment: Ahh, you're right, it not ID'd. Thanks, I'll see if that makes some change

Comment: Cheers so much for your help. It works now. Pointing out the obvious is very helpful :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet. I think some parts of the player is missing, and that is why `play() , pause(),` and `width()` is not defined.

Solution

Replace

```
vid.play(); and vid.pause();
```

with

```
Video.play(); and Video.pause();
```

Since you have invoked variable as Video, not vid.

```js
var Video = document.getElementById("YellowEyePenguinVid");

function PlayVid() {
  Video.play();
}

function PauseVid() {
  Video.pause();
}

function MaxScreen() {
  Video.width = 560;
}

function NorScreen() {
  Video.width = 260; // Brings video back to original size
}
```

```html
<button onclick="PlayVid()">Play</button>
<button onclick="PauseVid()">Pause</button>
<button onclick="MaxScreen()">Full Screen</button>
<button onclick="NorScreen()">Normal Size</button>
<div class="video">
  <video>
 <source src="YellowEyePenguinVid.mp4" type="video/mp4">         
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function with this

```
function PlayVid()
{
  Video.play(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't these:

```
   function PlayVid()
   {
       Video.play(); //instead of vid.play()  
   }
    function PauseVid()
    {
        Video.pause();  //instead of vid.pause()
    }
```

if you have error message in the console paste it here, if this would solve your problem you might had a log like :

```
can't read property play of undefined
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've changed them now and they work. Gradually getting used to the syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not have a link to scripts

you hava two option :
1.
write scripte on the page after titel
2.
write on javascript fille and put a link
under the titel
tip :
do alert on the function to see if its work!

Answer (score 0):

few things need to look over,

1. you didn't give the `id` attribute to `video` tag.
2. you created an instance as `Video` with "V" capital but, in reality, you are using `video` as small case

try below code out,

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <button onclick="PlayVid()">Play</button>
      <button onclick="PauseVid()">Pause</button>
      <button onclick="MaxScreen()">Full Screen</button>
      <button onclick="NorScreen()">Normal Size</button>
      <div class="video">
    
        <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
      </div>
    
      <script>
        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    
        function PlayVid() {
          vid.play();
        }
    
        function PauseVid() {
          vid.pause();
        }
    
        function MaxScreen() {
          vid.width = 560;
        }
    
        function NorScreen() {
          vid.width = 260; <!-- Brings video back to original size -->
        }
      </script>
      <p>Video courtesy of <a href="https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

I have used a live video source for the sake of visual testing. you could replace the source as per your wish